Have anyone know how to format the hard disk using uefi?
I have encountered a problem that I want my uefi system installed in the hard disk so I want to format the hard disk in GPT format using uefi.However,I cannot read the content of the file using uefi and failed to copy the efi files to complete my install.How to read the content of the file and how to format the hard disk that have uefi field to install the uefi app file in it?As tested,Read function in EFI_FILE_IO_PROTOCOL cannot read the content of file and in uefi all uefi functions have no way to format the hard disk to FAT32 format.
I want an answer using C language with edk or gnu-efi or baremetal.

If your hard disk is not formatted then what is running the program? If you are running an OS from a different disk then any standard programs may be used: parted, mkfs, tar, etc.

my cdrom is formatted,while my hard disk is not GPT and FAT32 formatted,I want my cdrom installed in the hard disk.

And linux commands is not vaild in UEFI-based bare machine.

All EFI does is boot.  Here is proces for CD https://oofhours.com/2021/12/25/how-does-uefi-boot-from-a-cd/

However,the CD's uefi cannot installed on the UEFI Machine if you don't copy the efi bootable files to the hard disk.

That's why all OS have an installer program.  Use efi to load the installer, which could be cut down Linux, and have an installer script that formats the disk and copies to the disk.

It's the fact,but I want to program the installer by using uefi APIs.

I want to build a house and have a credit card that can buy any tool I need. But I don't want to buy any tools, I want to use the credit card itself to build the house.

So uefi API is really a credit card not the tools?

Yes.  It can load any code into memory, including a whole OS, but does not know how to format hard disks or put shingles on a roof.

So does you have the source code of the OS installer to be downloaded by me?I cannot find any OS installer's source code even linux.

Kickstart is what I've most used. See https://wiki.debian.org/AutomatedInstallation
